# best practice for multiple select fields?

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I don't want to post the PHP code yet because I really don't think I have the best way of doing this.

Anyway here is what I am looking to accomplish.

I have a "classlist" table that has instructor led class information - including region and classtype.

I have "regions" table and a "classtype" table.  Right now people are able to choose their region or classtype from a drop down - works great.

But they want the option to choose multiple regions and classtypes - and these have to be search/sortable.  So when someone logs on they only see classes in their region by default.

I have created a helper table "regionhelper" that has fields - regionhelperid, regionid, and classlistid.  I am able to add multiple regions to a class -- works great.

But I would like the end-user to be able to see a select box with all of the regions and by them choosing 3 of the 12 regions they would update 3 rows on the regionhelper table.  Right?

If my process behind this is right how do I update multiple rows at once on a different table?

Comment: you will need javascipt i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to have a region helper table to store the extra regions. You can comma separate the regions in the DB then use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to iterate over them and get each region. This saves the complexity of having multiple tables unnecessarily.

E.g Paris,Nairobi,Montevideo

To get the individual regions during data retrieval, you can simply use:

```
    //Query to fetch region's field data for that user

     $data = explode(',', $regions);

    //The $data then stores the values in a numerically indexed array
    //So $data[0] = Paris
    //$data[1] = Nairobi
    //$data[2] = Montevideo
```

Comment: William The Dev -- thanks for your input.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Why did this get close?  Good answer!

Comment: I'd recommend http://codingforums.com if you require answers patiently and not curtly answered. The guys there are very patient. I'm called `RedCoder` in that forum. :-D

In StackOverflow things flow very fast and may frustrate you if you are not an expert.

Comment: Thanks - I will try codingforums too.  I have had a ton of questions answered here just by searching.  This is the first time I had to ask one.  I don't mind people being curt because I would hate to waste anyone's time.  Your answer was good because it was something I have used before and forgot... and offers a different way to do something right.  I am in no way a php/coding expert - my expertise lies in the CMS/LMS world.